# Por que en el hosting 000webhost no registra datos en la tabla?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, hosting

Tengo mi siguiente proyecto donde en mi localhost por medio de xampp si registra, llevo un avance y es por eso que ya lo subi a un host "000webhost", logre hacer la conexion... pero al momento de que quiero registrar algo sea la seccion que sea, me manda a la pagina con mi alerta de registro exitoso, pero al momento de verlo en la base de datos no registra nada.

Mi codigo es el siguiente

```
include 'ConBD.php';
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id14884512_19_", "passwordejemplo", "id14884512_condominioo");

//--------------------------------------
if (isset($_POST['btn_registrar'])) {
    
    //
    $NOMBRES = $_POST['NOMBRES'];
    $PATERNO = $_POST['AP'];
    $MATERNO = $_POST['AM'];
    $CALLE = $_POST['CALLE'];
    $EDIFICIO = $_POST['EDIFICIO'];
    $NUMERO = $_POST['NUMERO'];
    $FECHA_INGRESO = $_POST['FECHA_INGRESO'];
    $HORA_INGRESO = $_POST['HORA_INGRESO'];
    $FECHA_SALIDA = $_POST['FECHA_SALIDA'];
    $HORA_SALIDA = $_POST['HORA_SALIDA'];

    $COMPLETO = $NOMBRES . " " . $PATERNO . " " . $MATERNO;
    //
    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id14884512_19_", "Alex123$123456", "id14884512_condominio");
    $consulta = $conexion->query("INSERT INTO $database.control_acceso (ID_ACCESO, NOMBRES, PATERNO, MATERNO, COMPLETO, CALLE, EDIFICIO, NUMERO, FECHA_INGRESO, HORA_INGRESO, FECHA_SALIDA, HORA_SALIDA)
        VALUES (null, '$NOMBRES', '$PATERNO', '$MATERNO', '$COMPLETO','$CALLE', '$EDIFICIO', '$NUMERO','$FECHA_INGRESO','$HORA_INGRESO','$FECHA_SALIDA','$HORA_SALIDA')");
    header('location: ../Control_Acceso.php?m=1');
}
```

Comment: Y cambiaste los parametros de conexion al subirlo?

Comment: te refieres a mi archivo de "ConBD.php"?

Comment: Si, claro igual hice los cambios y sigue sin registrar

Comment: creaste la base de datos.. podes leer datos desde ella?

Comment: Si, leer si por que tengo secciones de consultas y si las puedo ver, pero insertar no puedo :/

Comment: Entonces vas a tener que agregar algun tipo de control de error.. porque si no graba, es por algo.. tenes algun error en la consola del navegador?

Comment: voy a checar eso, muchas gracias!

Comment: que se supone que es $database.control_acceso ? estas intentado insertar datos en una tabla cuyo nombre le pones $database.control_acceso por ende va a buscar la tabla llamada nombretabla.control_acceso

Comment: he quitado el $database

Comment: Ademas si tu base de datos tiene el id en autoincrement no necesitas enviar null en la insercion de datos, ademas debes verificar que ningun dato se este enviando vacio, porque entonces no lo registra

Comment: No sabes lo que ocurre porque faltan algunos controles en tu código: ¿hay conexión?, ¿hay datos vacíos?, ¿falló la consulta? Debes controlar cada una de esas posibilidades si quieres escribir un código robusto.

Comment: Ya vi la solucion jajaja me habia equivocado de tabla, grax bros